# Android google maps showing greed lines

Tags: android

I have one google maps application it does not show the maps it only shows the lines
It does not show the mapview,and i also have the internet Connection

```
      And it also genrate the following error
    09-30 12:01:12.934: WARN/Resources(587): Converting to string:             
    TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050002}
    09-30 12:01:13.094: WARN/GpsLocationProvider(59): Duplicate add listener for uid     
   10042
   09-30 12:01:13.334: INFO/MapActivity(587): Handling network change 
   notification:CONNECTED

  09-30 12:01:13.334: ERROR/MapActivity(587): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Showmap.java
        package de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps;

```
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.location.Location;
     import android.location.LocationListener;
     import android.location.LocationManager;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

     public class ShowMap extends MapActivity {

private MapController mapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity

    // create a map view
    RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoon 1 is world view
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 13,
            14, new GeoUpdateHandler());


}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);




    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

}

This is My mainfest
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name=".ShowMap"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
```

And main.xml

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
         android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:enabled="true"
                android:clickable="true"

             android:apiKey="0cHF-o_cvW1DEz3ocWAyybGqUsg8aUlwKMoyr4A"
             />
```

Comment: `greed` or `grid` !! do u use internet via proxy?

Comment: no i dont use internet via proxy

Comment: no i dont use internet via proxy

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the required permissions in place in the AndroidManifest.xml? In an Android app that I've made for GPS + Maps I have the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
```

Comment: Yes I have all the permission for the map

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with an API-Key.

[Here you can do it.](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

You need to generate different one for each emulator, device etc. and for final release, and you need to merge them with an keystore you're using, what sux, but there is no different way :/.

Good luck!